# How to post jenkins job result in jira?

Tags: jenkins, jira, jenkins-plugins, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am running jobs in Jenkins. I want to share the Jenkins job result in Jira. I have tried various plugins but failed to achieve my objective.

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin

If you also want to use this feature, you need to supply a valid user id/password. If you need the comment only to be visible to a certain JIRA group, e.g. Software Development, enter the groupname.

Now you also need to configure jobs. I figured you might not always have write access to the JIRA (say you have a Jenkins build for one of the Apache commons project that you depend on), so that's why this is optional.